# How to display data frames next to each other in html template or webpage without frames?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I want to display two data frames next to each other in html template

```
<h3> TITLE </h3>
 {{stat1 | safe}}.  {{stat | safe}}
```

I have tried this. But it displays data frames one below the other

Comment: Did you try html table or any reason why you dont want to consider it?

Comment: I have data frames of huge data. So it would be difficult to convert them into tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap them in `<div>` with `grid` styles.

```py
import jinja2 as jj
t=jj.Template("""
<h3> TITLE </h3>
<style>
div.df > div {white-space: pre-wrap;  display: grid;}
</style>
<div class='df' style='display:grid; grid-template-columns: 400px 400px ;'>
 <div>{{st  | safe}}</div>
 <div>{{st1 | safe}}</div>
<div>
""")
t.render(st=st,st1=st1)
```

[image: example_output]

Comment: Just a question to add on to this. Is is possible to make grid space dynamic? because the data frames might be bigger then 400px. And also how to get the data frames displayed in same level?